# ExtJs 4.2 Swap Style Sheet doesn't work correctly for me

Tags: javascript, extjs

Here is the part of my code related to theme changing.

in my javascript file:

```
loadTheme: function (theme) {
    document.getElementById('extjs-theme-css').href = "css/ext-all" + (theme == '' ? '' : '-') + theme + ".css";
    //OR (tried both ways, same issue)
    Ext.util.CSS.swapStyleSheet('extjs-theme-css', "css/ext-all" + (theme=='' ? '' : '-') + theme + ".css");
},
```

and in html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/extjs/v4.2/resources/css/ext-all-notheme.css" id="extjs-theme-css" />
```

When I first load up the web, all the windows and panels styles and positions are messed up.
After a browser refresh OR a mouse drag component resize, the styles and positions become correct again. (see pictures for what I mean). It happens every time I change a theme.

Same for IE, FF or Chrome. Tried on Default, Gray, Access, Neptune themes.

**first time (messed up, notice panel shifted out of window to right side)**

[image]

**Reload browser (looks fine, notice panel and window are positioned properly)**

[image]

Have I done anything wrong?

I have no luck fixing it. Please Help~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

Rixo had it exactly right -- you cannot change Ext themes on the fly for already rendered components.

The work-around is load the theme when the app starts.  To do this you need to store the chosen theme name somewhere where it can survive page refreshes.  ExtJS examples pages use query parameters, but I chose a cookie instead.  Inside my `index.jsp` I placed the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var consoleLogEnabled = true;
    var contextPath = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}";
    var theme = 'default';

    if (document.cookie) {
        index = document.cookie.indexOf('theme');
        if (index !== -1) {
            f = (document.cookie.indexOf("=", index) + 1);
            t = document.cookie.indexOf(";", index);
            if (t === -1) {
                t = document.cookie.length;
            }
            theme = (document.cookie.substring(f, t));
        }
    }

    if ((theme === 'default') || (theme !== 'gray' && theme !== 'access' && theme !== 'neptune'))
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/ext-js/resources/css/ext-all-debug.css" />');
    else
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/ext-js/resources/css/ext-all-' + theme + '-debug.css" />');

    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ext-js/ext-all-debug-w-comments.js"></scr'+'ipt>');

    if (theme === 'neptune')
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ext-js/ext-theme-neptune.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/myapp-style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myapp/myapp.js"></script>
```

Now when I want to change my theme I just do the following inside my controller:

```
changeTheme : function(theme) {
    if (theme !== Ext.util.Cookies.get('theme')) {
        Ext.util.Cookies.set('theme', theme);
        location = location; // Refresh of page cannot be avoided as its an Ext-JS limitation
    }
```

Viola - it Just Works.

Comment: Nice, currently we are just using themes of the same style to avoid the layout shifting problem. Now with a fix we can choose themes freely. I will give it a try.

Comment: I believe I found another problem however.  In order to use the neptune theme you need to do more than switch css.  You need to also load `ext-theme-neptune.js` which according to my jsfiddle messes up the classic blue theme.  See here:  http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?276703-Loading-ext-theme-neptune.js-messes-up-classic-theme

Comment: Check out the approach that Sencha uses on their examples.  They don't follow their own documention.  Instead they use some kind of black magic to rewrite script tags and reload the page via `location.search = ....`  http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs-build/examples/layout/border.html?theme=classic

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change Ext themes on the fly for already rendered components. The reason is that during the rendering process, Ext will read the style properties of generated DOM elements like border size, margins, etc., and use that information to determine the size of each elements. In most cases, this size is set in `style` property of the elements, and so it won't be affected by the change of the CSS rules.

So, if the rendered elements size is not the same for two different themes, the already rendered component will break in the way you've observed.

You can test this explanation by swapping between two themes that differs only by their colors, for example "Classic" and "Gray" themes. Components size won't be affected in this case.

Comment: Firstly, I am talking about first time load browser, I didn't say I change Ext themes on the fly. It screwed up the first time calling the swapStyleSheet() function from notheme (no such file) to a real theme. It fixed itself 2nd time reloading the browser and hit the swapStyleSheet() function again when you hit the browser Refresh button. Secondly, I did swap between "Classic" and "Gray" before I post, strangly the positions went off just like 'Neptune' anyway.....And question remains, What is swapStyleSheet() for? How can I use it correctly?